# Flutter - onGenerateRoute with Await for auth Guard

Tags: authentication, flutter, routes

I have a Flutter app with multiple pages, some pages require the user to be logged in, in order to access the page.

The main issue I am having is, for my `kDashboardRoute` I need to call an `async` method to check if the user is logged in and set the `bool isUserLoggedIn` accordingly, however, I can not call this method as it returns a future and I can not use `await` as the `routes` method can not return a future.

Any suggestions please?

Below is the code in my main.dart class

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  // run the app
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: kAppName,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        primaryColor: kPrimaryColour,
      ),
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.routes,
    ),
  );
}
```

Below is the code in my Routes File

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/services/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:myapp/utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:myapp/pages/login_page.dart';
import 'package:myapp/pages/two_step_verification.dart';
import 'package:myapp/pages/dashboard_page.dart';
import 'package:myapp/pages/error_page.dart';

class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> routes(RouteSettings settings) {
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case kLoginRoute:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage());
      case kTwoStepAuthRoute:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => TwoStepVerification());
      case kDashboardRoute:
        // TODO: call my auth check method here which required await
        bool isUserLoggedIn = true;  // set this accordingly 
        if (isUserLoggedIn == true) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DashboardPage());
        }

        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ErrorPage());
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage());
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see `onGenerateRoute` must return `Route`, so it must be synchronous and can't use `await`.

I think the easiest solution for provided situation would be to create a proxy page for dashboard that will consist of `FutureBuilder` where you can display some progress indicator while future is in progress and update it when result is obtained.

Another option would be to use `FutureBuilder` again but for whole MaterialApp class.

And if future is actually quite fast (reading from shared preferences or local database) then you can try to await for future result in `main` function before `runApp`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to run your auth check in the main function before runApp. The App will show the native splashscreen during this call (white screen by default, but it can be changed).